# Problem in reading Xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am making xml file for rssfeed. but rssfeed reader is not reading some special character.I have following data:

Machinery Vibration Analysis Training Course (with optional Mobius Institute certification **exam - ISO** 18436.2 Category II Vibration Analyst)

In **XML file** it looks like

Machinery Vibration Analysis Training Course (with optional Mobius Institute certification **exam  ISO** 18436.2 Category II Vibration Analyst)
when rssfeed reader read this xml file it shows xml error. please help me to solve this.

thank you

Comment: how about telling us the actual error message instead of just stating that there is one?

Comment: And you might want to show us some code, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function that converts all HTML entities to numeric XML entities. XML is particularly picky on this one if not defined in the DTD.